# Python Flask apps encountering '504 deadline error' when fetching secret versions from Google Secret Manager

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager, http-status-code-504

I have multiple Flask apps that rely on the Python Secret Manager client to fetch secret versions from Google Secret Manager. However, starting today, all of these apps are encountering a "504 deadline error" when they attempt to fetch the secret versions. The actual error is `google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded`

To provide some context, I am using the code example provided in the Google Secret Manager documentation for fetching secret versions: [link to the example code](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/samples/secretmanager-get-secret-version).

What's puzzling is that this error has suddenly occurred across all my Flask apps, even though I haven't made any code changes to some of them. I've also verified the service availability of Google Cloud services in my region, and there don't appear to be any reported problems or known issues.

Could I ask for help to understand what might be causing this sudden error across all my Flask apps? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to gRPC having troubles when used in combination with gevent. Try setting a different `worker_class` (not `gevent`) in [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html). The same applies to `gunicorn` for which you should not choose [`gevent` as the execution pool](https://distributedpython.com/posts/celery-execution-pools-what-is-it-all-about/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to solve the problem:

1. I noticed that on my ubuntu machine, when i executed ping, it was mapping to an IPv6 address instead of an IPv4 while, on my windows machine, it was mapping to IPv4. When I tried forcing ping to use IPv4, the ping works.
2. Next, I disabled all IPv6 in Ubuntu by editing one of the configuration files.
3. When I tried running all of my Flask apps they now work.

I don't know if there are any drawbacks for completely disabling IPv6 but this works for now.